# How do this casting work? About Polymorphism-CastingJava

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, run-time-polymorphism

Please don't be stuck in spelling mistakes. I didn't understand why Prof' saluer function is working with Prof arguments in the screen output.

***Code output:*** 
Mes hommages pour ma / mon collègue Neumann!

 
**My Person class.**

```
class Personne {
    String nom;


    Personne() {
        this("Anonymus");
    }

    Personne(String nom) {
        this.nom = nom;
    }

    String saluer(Personne p) {
        return this.nom + " salue " + p.nom + " !";
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "La personne " + nom + ".";
    }
}
```

**My other class (PROF)**

```
class Prof extends Personne {
    String nomCours = "Java";

    Prof() {
    }

    Prof(String arg) {
        this("NoName", arg);
    }

    Prof(String arg1, String arg2) {
        super(arg1);
        this.nomCours = arg2;
    }

    String saluer(Prof p) {
        return "Mes hommages pour ma/mon collègue " + p.nom + " !";
    }

    String saluer(Personne p) {
        return "La/le prof " + this.nom + " présente ses hommages à " + p.nom + " !";
    }

    String saluer(Etudiant e) {
        if (this.nomCours.equals(e.nomCours))
            return "Bonjour à mon étudiant(e) " + e.nom + " !";
        return "Bonjour de la part de " + this.nom + " !";
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Le prof " + nom + " donne le cours " + nomCours + ".";
    }
}
```

**My main class**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Personne mixte1 = new Prof("Poincaré", "Math");
    Personne mixte2 = new Prof("Neumann", "Info");
    Personne mixte3 = new Etudiant("Toi", "Info");

    System.out.println(mixte1.saluer(((Prof)mixte2)));  // problem here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `saluer()` method takes a `Personne` object, and your `Prof` object is extending `Personne`, so this means you (or, in this case, the compiler) can cast `Prof` to `Personne` without any errors, because they are based on the same class.

You can always cast upwards in the inheritance tree

```
Personne
  |
  +-- Prof
  |
  +-- Etudiant
```

It would also be possible to cast an `Etudiant` to a Personne. Or, you can cast an Etudiant to a `Personne` and then back to an `Etudiant`, that would work too. But you cannot cast an `Etudiant` to a `Prof`, because they are on the same level in the inheritance tree.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the class `Personne` does not have a method `saluer`that takes another `Personne`as argument. Your class `Prof`does, but at that line in the code, the compiler does not know this. You could (for example) write:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Personne mixte1 = new Prof("Poincaré", "Math");
    Personne mixte2 = new Prof("Neumann", "Info");
    Personne mixte3 = new Etudiant("Toi", "Info");

    System.out.println(((Prof)mixte1).saluer(mixte2);  // problem here

}
```

To answer the general question: The Java-compiler tries to know as best as it can, which object's methods you are calling. When you try to call `mixte1.saluer((Prof) mixte2)`, you mistakenly think, that the compiler knows that the method `saluer(Prof prof)` exists with mixte1, but you 'downcast' `mixte1` to a `Personne`, and therefore the compiler does not know this.